# Symfony2 map 2 entities to one entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

please, do you have some solution, how to map 2 or more entities with other one? I have entity file. I want to map file to Text, Product... It means, that I upload file, it saves file into database and I want to be able to map file to Text or Product. What is the best way to do this? Thank you

EDIT:

- http://pastebin.com/KFQiM3ic  File.php
- http://pastebin.com/TiBK9Uk1  Text.php  - Product.php is same as Text, but it has other table in database...

Comment: I haven´t tried anything yet, because I was googling and I didn´t find any solution.

Comment: OK, this is very general question. Can you please describe more what you're trying to achieve? Start by describing better your entities...

Comment: So I have entity File, where I save uploaded files. Than I have entities Text and now I´m working on entity Product. I want to be able to map File to Text or Product, but I don´t know, how to make it - how to differentiate if File is mapped to Text or Product.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two entities mapping to the same place? The proper way would be to add two Forms but one entity. You will have redundant code doing this way. One entity is all you need.

Comment: Why? Because I want to be able, to add file to text or product and I´m  finding way to map it and differentiate if it is file mapped to text or product. One way is to set manually into database, if it is mapped to text or product - I will set e.g. "object_name" so row in table might look like like this:

**object_id   object_name   file_id \n
2           text          6         \n
3           product       7** but if I would do it like this, it will be quite hard to get it from database, so I want to find out, if doctrine has some solution to my problem

Comment: Ok. I added it to main question

Comment: Do you understand that mapping means going to one database table? What you are asking to do is have two sets of code that update the same database when one set of code will suffice.

Comment: I didn´t know, that mapping is only to one table. So how to make it please?